# Making images responsive for mobile site/browser

Tags: html, css

I have a image which works perfectly in `browser`, but when i come to mobile site. It does not fit the width of the browser.

```css
.bcg {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Slide 1 */
#slide-1 .bcg {background-image:url('../img/1-1.png'); max-width: 100%}

/* Slide 2 */
#slide-2 .bcg {background-image:url('../img/2-2.png'); max-width: 100%}

/* Slide 3 */
#slide-3 .bcg {background-image:url('../img/3-3.png'); max-width: 100%}

/* Slide 4 */
#slide-4 .bcg {background-image:url('../img/4-4.png'); max-width: 100%}
```

I have placed max-width: 100% to my images, yet its not responsive when the `browser` size reduces.

Comment: You should look more into responsive web design.  Heres a helpful link: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Well ofcourse it dosen't work, the `max-width:100%;` works only on normal images, whreas all I can figure out from your code is that your images are used as a background for some element and `max-width:100%;` is not for background images.

Comment: With max width you're saying the .bcg can have a (max-width) maximum width of 100%, and should also always have a width of 100% of the parent - but the background you're setting to these slide ID's isn't going to scale with that unless a background size is set - ( background-size: 100%, contain, or cover.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to make images responsive you can wrap the images inside a container and give it 100% width. Then set the img as width:100% and height:auto; and it will magically resize following the size of its container.

```
div{width:100%;}
img{width:100%; height:auto;}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/atsFA/13/

Try resizing the browser and you will see that image resize together with the container.

In your case you are not using img tags but background-images so you can just use `background-size:cover;` and you don't need to set a max-width.

```
.bcg {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#slide-1 .bcg {background-image:url('../img/1-1.png'); background-size:cover;}    

#slide-2 .bcg {background-image:url('../img/2-2.png'); background-size:cover;}    

#slide-3 .bcg {background-image:url('../img/3-3.png'); background-size:cover;}    

#slide-4 .bcg {background-image:url('../img/4-4.png'); background-size:cover;}
```

**EDIT**

I have edited my fiddle. In your case `background-size:cover;` was not working because you always need to have a width and a height set explicitly for your container.

http://jsfiddle.net/atsFA/15/

Comment: background-size: cover is not working... your first fiddle works pefectly, but i can't implement that.

Comment: no problem, just show me a fiddle or your html structure and I will help you out.

Comment: So try now again but set a height for each of the #slide container and  get the code from the fiddle I have just updated. I hope it helps :)